# Add all Firefox Certificates to Ubuntu 18.04 trust store

Tags: 18.04, firefox, certificates

What is the best way to add all common used **Intermediate** Certificates in Ubuntu 18.04+, and keep them up2date with apt? I mean typical intermediate certs signed from Digicert, Comodo, etc.

It seems that Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server does not have all common (newer) used Intermediate Certificates in it's trust store.

For example: **Thawte EV RSA CA 2018** (Intermediate) signed by Digicert (Root) is **not available** in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla and/or /etc/ssl/certs/.

But: In Firefox this Intermediate it's available (checked in Windows, Firefox 62.0.3).

Is there a cert-bundle package or similar we should use? Or do I have to install firefox to use them (its a server without UI..)